# Capture Ace Editor Inside a table

Tags: html, css, text, editor, ace-editor

So I'm trying to use Ace Editor to allow you to edit code. I want one side to display the text editor and one side to display the outcome of the code. My problem is, Ace Editor doesn't do inside of a table. http://prntscr.com/3q2xwd What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are adding `position:absolute` style to the editor, it seems to work fine here http://jsbin.com/ojijeb/609/edit

Answer (score 0):

Since no answer has been accepted yet, and the link provided by the user no longer works, I suggest to use the following style for the Ace Editor (instead of the suggestion of the [front page](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=embedding)):

```
#editor {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

In the repository, there are also other examples showing how to embed the editor, see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/tree/master/demo.